# Scrapy missing Tutorial folder when starting a project

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

Having done the command:
`scrapy startproject <projectname>`
I don't have a folder named "Tutorial".

As a result, executing my spider ends up with a notification:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tutorial'

I installed the scrapy on another machine and got the same result.

What am I doing wrong?

P.S. The question on the stackoverflow "Scrapy -— Error ImportError: No module named tutorial.settings" is a different one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you do this exactly?
Maybe you're in the wrong directory, you should by in the directory containing scrapy.cfg and a folder called tutorial.

```
scrapy startproject tutorial      // create scrapy project
cd tutorial                       // go into scrapy project directory, do not go into the second folder named tutorial aswell.
scrapy crawl <spider_name>        // run spider
```

Also, how does the project structure look now? It should look like this:

```
tutorial/
    tutorial/
        settings.py
        spiders
        ...
    scrapy.cfg
```